# LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #1 module="go" function="runtime.resetMemoryDataView" error: function import requires a callable

Tags: go, webassembly

As I'm building my Web assembly application I have bumped into issue with a cryptic error:

**LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #1 module="go" function="runtime.resetMemoryDataView" error: function import requires a callable**

It is compiled with this command:

**GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm main.go server.go**

This is the body of index.html, there is nothing in

```
<body class="is-preload">
    <script src="wasm_exec.js"></script>
    <script>
    wasm_filename = "main.wasm";    
    function message(s){
        document.getElementById("message").textContent = s;
    }

    function load_wasm(){
        if (!WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming) { // polyfill
            WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming = async (resp, importObject) => {
                const source = await (await resp).arrayBuffer();
                return await WebAssembly.instantiate(source, importObject);
            };
        }

        const go = new Go();

        WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch(wasm_filename), go.importObject)
        .then(results => { go.run(results.instance); })
        .catch((err) => {
            message("Error Loading WebAssembly - " + err);
            console.error(err);
    //      location.reload(true);
            });
    }

    load_wasm()
</script>
```

This is main.go:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "syscall/js"
)

func key(this js.Value, arg []js.Value) interface{} {
    arg[0].Call("stopPropagation")
    arg[0].Call("preventDefault")
    return nil
}

func sum(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    var rv interface{}
    value1 := js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", args[0].String()).Get("value").String()
    value2 := js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", args[1].String()).Get("value").String()

    int1, _ := strconv.Atoi(value1)
    int2, _ := strconv.Atoi(value2)

    js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", "result").Set("value", int1+int2)
    return rv
}

func register_callbacks() {
    js.Global().Set("key", js.FuncOf(key))
    js.Global().Set("sum", js.FuncOf(sum))
}

func init() {
    register_callbacks()
    fmt.Printf("WebAssembly program started\n")
    select {}
}
```

Then we have the server:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

var listen = flag.String("listen", ":8081", "listen address")
var dir = flag.String("dir", ".", "directory to serve")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets/"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    fmt.Printf("Web server running. Listening on %q", *listen)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(*listen, http.FileServer(http.Dir(*dir)))
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
}
```

This is wasm_exec.js:

```
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

(() => {
    if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
        // global already exists
    } else if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.global = window;
    } else if (typeof self !== "undefined") {
        self.global = self;
    } else {
        throw new Error("cannot export Go (neither global, window nor self is defined)");
    }

    // Map web browser API and Node.js API to a single common API (preferring web standards over Node.js API).
    const isNodeJS = global.process && global.process.title === "node";
    if (isNodeJS) {
        global.require = require;
        global.fs = require("fs");

        const nodeCrypto = require("crypto");
        global.crypto = {
            getRandomValues(b) {
                nodeCrypto.randomFillSync(b);
            },
        };

        global.performance = {
            now() {
                const [sec, nsec] = process.hrtime();
                return sec * 1000 + nsec / 1000000;
            },
        };

        const util = require("util");
        global.TextEncoder = util.TextEncoder;
        global.TextDecoder = util.TextDecoder;
    } else {
        let outputBuf = "";
        global.fs = {
            constants: { O_WRONLY: -1, O_RDWR: -1, O_CREAT: -1, O_TRUNC: -1, O_APPEND: -1, O_EXCL: -1 }, // unused
            writeSync(fd, buf) {
                outputBuf += decoder.decode(buf);
                const nl = outputBuf.lastIndexOf("\n");
                if (nl != -1) {
                    console.log(outputBuf.substr(0, nl));
                    outputBuf = outputBuf.substr(nl + 1);
                }
                return buf.length;
            },
            write(fd, buf, offset, length, position, callback) {
                if (offset !== 0 || length !== buf.length || position !== null) {
                    throw new Error("not implemented");
                }
                const n = this.writeSync(fd, buf);
                callback(null, n);
            },
            open(path, flags, mode, callback) {
                const err = new Error("not implemented");
                err.code = "ENOSYS";
                callback(err);
            },
            read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback) {
                const err = new Error("not implemented");
                err.code = "ENOSYS";
                callback(err);
            },
            fsync(fd, callback) {
                callback(null);
            },
        };
    }

    const encoder = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
    const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");

    global.Go = class {
        constructor() {
            this.argv = ["js"];
            this.env = {};
            this.exit = (code) => {
                if (code !== 0) {
                    console.warn("exit code:", code);
                }
            };
            this._exitPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
                this._resolveExitPromise = resolve;
            });
            this._pendingEvent = null;
            this._scheduledTimeouts = new Map();
            this._nextCallbackTimeoutID = 1;

            const mem = () => {
                // The buffer may change when requesting more memory.
                return new DataView(this._inst.exports.mem.buffer);
            }

            const setInt64 = (addr, v) => {
                mem().setUint32(addr + 0, v, true);
                mem().setUint32(addr + 4, Math.floor(v / 4294967296), true);
            }

            const getInt64 = (addr) => {
                const low = mem().getUint32(addr + 0, true);
                const high = mem().getInt32(addr + 4, true);
                return low + high * 4294967296;
            }

            const loadValue = (addr) => {
                const f = mem().getFloat64(addr, true);
                if (f === 0) {
                    return undefined;
                }
                if (!isNaN(f)) {
                    return f;
                }

                const id = mem().getUint32(addr, true);
                return this._values[id];
            }

            const storeValue = (addr, v) => {
                const nanHead = 0x7FF80000;

                if (typeof v === "number") {
                    if (isNaN(v)) {
                        mem().setUint32(addr + 4, nanHead, true);
                        mem().setUint32(addr, 0, true);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (v === 0) {
                        mem().setUint32(addr + 4, nanHead, true);
                        mem().setUint32(addr, 1, true);
                        return;
                    }
                    mem().setFloat64(addr, v, true);
                    return;
                }

                switch (v) {
                    case undefined:
                        mem().setFloat64(addr, 0, true);
                        return;
                    case null:
                        mem().setUint32(addr + 4, nanHead, true);
                        mem().setUint32(addr, 2, true);
                        return;
                    case true:
                        mem().setUint32(addr + 4, nanHead, true);
                        mem().setUint32(addr, 3, true);
                        return;
                    case false:
                        mem().setUint32(addr + 4, nanHead, true);
                        mem().setUint32(addr, 4, true);
                        return;
                }

                let ref = this._refs.get(v);
                if (ref === undefined) {
                    ref = this._values.length;
                    this._values.push(v);
                    this._refs.set(v, ref);
                }
                let typeFlag = 0;
                switch (typeof v) {
                    case "string":
                        typeFlag = 1;
                        break;
                    case "symbol":
                        typeFlag = 2;
                        break;
                    case "function":
                        typeFlag = 3;
                        break;
                }
                mem().setUint32(addr + 4, nanHead | typeFlag, true);
                mem().setUint32(addr, ref, true);
            }

            const loadSlice = (addr) => {
                const array = getInt64(addr + 0);
                const len = getInt64(addr + 8);
                return new Uint8Array(this._inst.exports.mem.buffer, array, len);
            }

            const loadSliceOfValues = (addr) => {
                const array = getInt64(addr + 0);
                const len = getInt64(addr + 8);
                const a = new Array(len);
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    a[i] = loadValue(array + i * 8);
                }
                return a;
            }

            const loadString = (addr) => {
                const saddr = getInt64(addr + 0);
                const len = getInt64(addr + 8);
                return decoder.decode(new DataView(this._inst.exports.mem.buffer, saddr, len));
            }

            const timeOrigin = Date.now() - performance.now();
            this.importObject = {
                go: {
                    // Go's SP does not change as long as no Go code is running. Some operations (e.g. calls, getters and setters)
                    // may synchronously trigger a Go event handler. This makes Go code get executed in the middle of the imported
                    // function. A goroutine can switch to a new stack if the current stack is too small (see morestack function).
                    // This changes the SP, thus we have to update the SP used by the imported function.

                    // func wasmExit(code int32)
                    "runtime.wasmExit": (sp) => {
                        const code = mem().getInt32(sp + 8, true);
                        this.exited = true;
                        delete this._inst;
                        delete this._values;
                        delete this._refs;
                        this.exit(code);
                    },

                    // func wasmWrite(fd uintptr, p unsafe.Pointer, n int32)
                    "runtime.wasmWrite": (sp) => {
                        const fd = getInt64(sp + 8);
                        const p = getInt64(sp + 16);
                        const n = mem().getInt32(sp + 24, true);
                        fs.writeSync(fd, new Uint8Array(this._inst.exports.mem.buffer, p, n));
                    },

                    // func nanotime() int64
                    "runtime.nanotime": (sp) => {
                        setInt64(sp + 8, (timeOrigin + performance.now()) * 1000000);
                    },

                    // func walltime() (sec int64, nsec int32)
                    "runtime.walltime": (sp) => {
                        const msec = (new Date).getTime();
                        setInt64(sp + 8, msec / 1000);
                        mem().setInt32(sp + 16, (msec % 1000) * 1000000, true);
                    },

                    // func scheduleTimeoutEvent(delay int64) int32
                    "runtime.scheduleTimeoutEvent": (sp) => {
                        const id = this._nextCallbackTimeoutID;
                        this._nextCallbackTimeoutID++;
                        this._scheduledTimeouts.set(id, setTimeout(
                            () => { this._resume(); },
                            getInt64(sp + 8) + 1, // setTimeout has been seen to fire up to 1 millisecond early
                        ));
                        mem().setInt32(sp + 16, id, true);
                    },

                    // func clearTimeoutEvent(id int32)
                    "runtime.clearTimeoutEvent": (sp) => {
                        const id = mem().getInt32(sp + 8, true);
                        clearTimeout(this._scheduledTimeouts.get(id));
                        this._scheduledTimeouts.delete(id);
                    },

                    // func getRandomData(r []byte)
                    "runtime.getRandomData": (sp) => {
                        crypto.getRandomValues(loadSlice(sp + 8));
                    },

                    // func stringVal(value string) ref
                    "syscall/js.stringVal": (sp) => {
                        storeValue(sp + 24, loadString(sp + 8));
                    },

                    // func valueGet(v ref, p string) ref
                    "syscall/js.valueGet": (sp) => {
                        const result = Reflect.get(loadValue(sp + 8), loadString(sp + 16));
                        sp = this._inst.exports.getsp(); // see comment above
                        storeValue(sp + 32, result);
                    },

                    // func valueSet(v ref, p string, x ref)
                    "syscall/js.valueSet": (sp) => {
                        Reflect.set(loadValue(sp + 8), loadString(sp + 16), loadValue(sp + 32));
                    },

                    // func valueIndex(v ref, i int) ref
                    "syscall/js.valueIndex": (sp) => {
                        storeValue(sp + 24, Reflect.get(loadValue(sp + 8), getInt64(sp + 16)));
                    },

                    // valueSetIndex(v ref, i int, x ref)
                    "syscall/js.valueSetIndex": (sp) => {
                        Reflect.set(loadValue(sp + 8), getInt64(sp + 16), loadValue(sp + 24));
                    },

                    // func valueCall(v ref, m string, args []ref) (ref, bool)
                    "syscall/js.valueCall": (sp) => {
                        try {
                            const v = loadValue(sp + 8);
                            const m = Reflect.get(v, loadString(sp + 16));
                            const args = loadSliceOfValues(sp + 32);
                            const result = Reflect.apply(m, v, args);
                            sp = this._inst.exports.getsp(); // see comment above
                            storeValue(sp + 56, result);
                            mem().setUint8(sp + 64, 1);
                        } catch (err) {
                            storeValue(sp + 56, err);
                            mem().setUint8(sp + 64, 0);
                        }
                    },

                    // func valueInvoke(v ref, args []ref) (ref, bool)
                    "syscall/js.valueInvoke": (sp) => {
                        try {
                            const v = loadValue(sp + 8);
                            const args = loadSliceOfValues(sp + 16);
                            const result = Reflect.apply(v, undefined, args);
                            sp = this._inst.exports.getsp(); // see comment above
                            storeValue(sp + 40, result);
                            mem().setUint8(sp + 48, 1);
                        } catch (err) {
                            storeValue(sp + 40, err);
                            mem().setUint8(sp + 48, 0);
                        }
                    },

                    // func valueNew(v ref, args []ref) (ref, bool)
                    "syscall/js.valueNew": (sp) => {
                        try {
                            const v = loadValue(sp + 8);
                            const args = loadSliceOfValues(sp + 16);
                            const result = Reflect.construct(v, args);
                            sp = this._inst.exports.getsp(); // see comment above
                            storeValue(sp + 40, result);
                            mem().setUint8(sp + 48, 1);
                        } catch (err) {
                            storeValue(sp + 40, err);
                            mem().setUint8(sp + 48, 0);
                        }
                    },

                    // func valueLength(v ref) int
                    "syscall/js.valueLength": (sp) => {
                        setInt64(sp + 16, parseInt(loadValue(sp + 8).length));
                    },

                    // valuePrepareString(v ref) (ref, int)
                    "syscall/js.valuePrepareString": (sp) => {
                        const str = encoder.encode(String(loadValue(sp + 8)));
                        storeValue(sp + 16, str);
                        setInt64(sp + 24, str.length);
                    },

                    // valueLoadString(v ref, b []byte)
                    "syscall/js.valueLoadString": (sp) => {
                        const str = loadValue(sp + 8);
                        loadSlice(sp + 16).set(str);
                    },

                    // func valueInstanceOf(v ref, t ref) bool
                    "syscall/js.valueInstanceOf": (sp) => {
                        mem().setUint8(sp + 24, loadValue(sp + 8) instanceof loadValue(sp + 16));
                    },

                    "debug": (value) => {
                        console.log(value);
                    },
                }
            };
        }

        async run(instance) {
            this._inst = instance;
            this._values = [ // TODO: garbage collection
                NaN,
                0,
                null,
                true,
                false,
                global,
                this._inst.exports.mem,
                this,
            ];
            this._refs = new Map();
            this.exited = false;

            const mem = new DataView(this._inst.exports.mem.buffer)

            // Pass command line arguments and environment variables to WebAssembly by writing them to the linear memory.
            let offset = 4096;

            const strPtr = (str) => {
                let ptr = offset;
                new Uint8Array(mem.buffer, offset, str.length + 1).set(encoder.encode(str + "\0"));
                offset += str.length + (8 - (str.length % 8));
                return ptr;
            };

            const argc = this.argv.length;

            const argvPtrs = [];
            this.argv.forEach((arg) => {
                argvPtrs.push(strPtr(arg));
            });

            const keys = Object.keys(this.env).sort();
            argvPtrs.push(keys.length);
            keys.forEach((key) => {
                argvPtrs.push(strPtr(`${key}=${this.env[key]}`));
            });

            const argv = offset;
            argvPtrs.forEach((ptr) => {
                mem.setUint32(offset, ptr, true);
                mem.setUint32(offset + 4, 0, true);
                offset += 8;
            });

            this._inst.exports.run(argc, argv);
            if (this.exited) {
                this._resolveExitPromise();
            }
            await this._exitPromise;
        }

        _resume() {
            if (this.exited) {
                throw new Error("Go program has already exited");
            }
            this._inst.exports.resume();
            if (this.exited) {
                this._resolveExitPromise();
            }
        }

        _makeFuncWrapper(id) {
            const go = this;
            return function () {
                const event = { id: id, this: this, args: arguments };
                go._pendingEvent = event;
                go._resume();
                return event.result;
            };
        }
    }

    if (isNodeJS) {
        if (process.argv.length < 3) {
            process.stderr.write("usage: go_js_wasm_exec [wasm binary] [arguments]\n");
            process.exit(1);
        }

        const go = new Go();
        go.argv = process.argv.slice(2);
        go.env = Object.assign({ TMPDIR: require("os").tmpdir() }, process.env);
        go.exit = process.exit;
        WebAssembly.instantiate(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]), go.importObject).then((result) => {
            process.on("exit", (code) => { // Node.js exits if no event handler is pending
                if (code === 0 && !go.exited) {
                    // deadlock, make Go print error and stack traces
                    go._pendingEvent = { id: 0 };
                    go._resume();
                }
            });
            return go.run(result.instance);
        }).catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Does the `wasm_exec.js` come from same distribution of `go` that was used to compile code?

Comment: wasm_exec.js comes from an example that works. I am trying to build this app based on working components.

Comment: Note that `wasm_exec.js` evolves with go compiler and language itself so it is really important to take `wasm_exec.js` from `$(go env GOROOT)/misc/wasm/wasm_exec.js`. To explain my triage path - `runtime.resetMemoryDataView` is javascript glue function that comes from `wasm_exec.js` and usually those problems arise from using older version of file and runtime with newer wasm binary not understood by older runtime.

Comment: Error gone. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`runtime.resetMemoryDataView()` function is part of `wasm_exec.js` support script that bridges WebAssembly binary with JavaScript environment. This and similar errors often mean that `wasm_exec.js` isn't compatible with WebAssembly binary because version of Golang used to compile binary is different (usually newer) than one `wasm_exec.js` was taken from.

When running or shipping Golang WebAssembly binary always make sure that you are using `wasm_exec.js` support script from the same version of Golang as was used to compile binary. You can copy it from `$(go env GOROOT)/misc/wasm/wasm_exec.js` to be sure.

See official Golang [WebAssembly wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WebAssembly) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

As blami suggested a simple:

```sh
cp $(go env GOROOT)/misc/wasm/wasm_exec.js ./path/to/old/wasm_exec.js
```

Worked for me.